# Flutter: Use different colors on text according to the situation

Tags: android, flutter

I have a app that receives order data from an api and show them on a listview.
There are 4 statuses (ok, waiting, pending and complete) and i wanna show any status with a color but i dont know how i would do that.

Any ideas?

My code:
Creating the objects:

```
class Hist {
  final String codPedido;
  final String status;
  final String statusDescricao;
  final String usuario;
  final String placa;
  final String box;
  final String tipoVeiculo;
  final String dtCadastro;
  final String hrCadastro;

  Hist(
      {this.codPedido,
      this.status,
      this.statusDescricao,
      this.usuario,
      this.placa,
      this.box,
      this.tipoVeiculo,
      this.dtCadastro,
      this.hrCadastro});

  factory Hist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Hist(
        codPedido: json['cod_pedido'],
        status: json['status'],
        statusDescricao: json['status_descricao'],
        usuario: json['usuario'],
        placa: json['placa'],
        box: json['box'],
        tipoVeiculo: json['tipo_veiculo'],
        dtCadastro: json['dt_cadastro'],
        hrCadastro: json['hr_cadastro']);
  }
}
```

The builder:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Hist>>(
      future: _fetchHist(context),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<Hist> data = snapshot.data;
          return _histListView(data);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
        }
        return Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              strokeWidth: 2.0,
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.green),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

The fetch part:

```
  Future<List<Hist>> _fetchHist(BuildContext context) async {
    //Classe para carregar os pedidos da api
    //
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); //pega o usuário logado
    final key = 'usuario';
    final value = prefs.getString(key);
    print('saved tester $value');
    String usu = value; //fim

    //Carrega os itens da api
    Response response = await Dio().post(
        server,
        data: {"usuario": usu});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.data);
      print(response.data);
      return jsonResponse.map((job) => new Hist.fromJson(job)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Falha ao carregar histórico');
    }
  }
```

the listview and tile parts:

```
  ListView _histListView(data) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return _tile(
              data[index].codPedido + " - " + data[index].hrCadastro,
              "Status: " +
                  data[index].statusDescricao +
                  "\nBox: " +
                  data[index].box +
                  " " +
                  data[index].tipoVeiculo +
                  " " +
                  data[index].placa,
              Icons.settings,
              context,
              index);
        });
  }

  ListTile _tile(String title, String subtitle, IconData icon,
          BuildContext context, int counter) =>
      ListTile(
        title: Text(title,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              fontSize: 20,
            )),
        subtitle: Text(subtitle),
        leading: Icon(
          icon,
          color: Colors.green[500],
        ),
        onTap: () {
          _fetchPed(title);
          for (int i = 0; i < dataHolder.length; i++) {
            pedList.add(Ped.fromJson(dataHolder[0]));
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you, you want to achieve different color for text. You can create function which checks the status and passes the color according to it

```
         Color checkStatus(String st){
         Color a;
          if(st=="OK") 
           a=Colors.red;
         else if
           .... other statuses
```

And  in your text you will get like this:

```
       Text("my status", color: checkStatus("OK"))
```

Comment: I should call the function on the list tiles, right? But there are other data on the row, like order cod, time etc, doint this all of them would be affected by the function, isn't it?

Comment: call this in your text widget where you want to get colored Text, if your texts are in one text widget then separate it from others

Answer (score 0):

why don't you create a color field in your class then when you create the class initialize the color like this.

```
class Hist {
  String status;
  Color color;

  Hist({this.status}) {
    _intialize();
  }

  _intialize() {
    if (status == 'Ok') {
      color = Colors.pink;
    } else if (status == 'waiting') {
      color = Colors.orange;
    }
    //Rest of your conditions 
  }
}

//Then you would use it like this
Hist hist = Hist(status: 'waiting');


Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          color: hist.color,
        ),
```

I am using the color property on a container but obviously you could use it anywhere